# jQuery prevAll with first selector

Tags: jquery

I try to use jQuery prevAll to get the first object with a specific selector of another list of objects

The expected result is that primary3 and primary2 will be affected but the actual result is that only primary3 is affected! if I remove ".first" selector primary3, primary2 and primary1 are affected.
What I need is given a list of objects x I want to select the first previous object matching a selector for each item of list x. Is there a one liner to achieve this using jQuery?

https://moimsd.w3spaces.com/jquery_prevAll.html

```js
$("li.selected").prevAll(".primary").first().css({
  "color": "red",
  "border": "2px solid red"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="primary">primary1</li>
  <li class="secondary">secondary</li>
  <li class="secondary">secondary)</li>
  <li class="primary">primary2</li>
  <li class="secondary">secondary</li>
  <li class="secondary selected">secondary</li>
  <li class="secondary">secondary</li>
  <li class="primary">primary3</li>
  <li class="secondary">secondary</li>
  <li class="secondary selected">secondary</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, The code you posted needs and an explicit loop. I thought there could be a one liner with no explicit loop that may do task. 
How could you change the code in my question!?

Comment: I showed you how to achieve what you want to achieve. There is no "one-liner" to do this in jQuery.